# Python - Pandas Dataframe get avarage of n rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, aggregation

Just to make that clear at the start. I'm talking about `rows`  and not about `columns`:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jikOF.png

I am working with a `pandas Dataframe` that saves multiple decibel Values. My job is it to get the `average` of n rows. I get the values from an `.wav file` where I run an `stft function` to save the data saved in the `.wav file` into an `pd.Dataframe.` Because I work with large files I have to `aggregate` the `Dataframe` in order to save `DiskSpace`.

I already have an algorithm that calculates `n`, the aggregation, so I only need to run the command to do so.

for example:
When the aggregation `n` is 4 the Dataframe should be converted from:

this:

```
2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16  ...

3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24 ...
...
```

into this:

```
{2, 4, 6, 8}, {10, 12, 14, 16}  ... ,{3, 6, 9, 12}, {15, 18, 21, 24} ...
```

to this:

```
{5}, {13} ... {7.5}, {19.5} ...
```

and in the end to a new Dataframe:

```
5, 13, ...
7.5, 19.5, ...
...
```

This is the Dataframe I'm working with:

```
         0          1          2    ...        510        511        512

 0  -50.148830 -50.731472 -58.459068  ... -80.000000 -80.000000 -80.000000

 1  -49.234821 -49.215736 -57.735603  ... -80.000000 -80.000000 -80.000000

 2  -53.309082 -53.790737 -61.091209  ... -80.000000 -80.000000 -80.000000

 3  -50.511078 -51.120682 -59.740089  ... -80.000000 -80.000000 -80.000000

 4  -52.077423 -51.985920 -59.107773  ... -80.000000 -80.000000 -80.000000

 5  -47.280487 -47.177921 -56.507130  ... -80.000000 -80.000000 -80.000000
```

so when we take a look how the first line should change when `n` is three:

```
 0  -50.148830 -50.731472 -58.459068  ... -80.000000 -80.000000 -80.000000
```

They get `"grouped"`:

```
 array = [{-50.148830, -50.731472, -58.459068}, ..., {-80.000000, -80.000000, -80.000000}, ...];
```

Then the avarage/`mean()?` the `array`

```
array = [{-53.1131}, ..., {-80.000000}, ...];
```

But instead of doing this to only one line do it to all of them and convert them back into an `pd.Dataframe`.

```
        0     ...    512

 0  -53.1131  ... -80.000000

 1  -52.0620  ... -80.000000

 2  -56.0636  ... -80.000000

 3  -53.7906  ... -80.000000

 4  -54.3904  ... -80.000000

 5  -50.3219  ... -80.000000
```

I tried the groupby function but I always get an Value Error:

```
n = 3
pd.Dataframe = data

grouped = data.groupby(np.arange(len(data)) // n, axis=1).mean()
```

output:

```
ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length
```

I couldn't find a solution on the internet so any help is appreciated :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'The grouper and axis should be of same length': In your code, the grouper here is len(data) (number of rows) and axis is 1 which are actually different.
So it should be either

```
data.groupby(np.arange(len(data)) // n, axis=0).mean()
```

or

```
data.groupby(np.arange(len(data.columns)) // n, axis=1).mean()
```

In your case, it seems that you want to groupby by columns, so the latter version should work